# Maximize retention

Tags: secondary-education, mathematical-pedagogy

I tutor high school math students. Students often struggle with a problem they had completed few months prior. Like any skill, it's natural to forget what you learned after a while.

As high school instructors/teachers/tutors, **how do you maximize retention of a skill and how to quickly get the student to recall/relearn what was forgotten? How often do you assess students' retention of previous topics outside of finals, eg if quadratics was introduced early in the semester, include a question requiring solving quadratics in the current unit assessment?**

In many Asian and Eastern European countries, students drill through tons of (often similar) problems while in my experience this is not as emphasized in North America, where a stronger focus is on exploration. Do either muscle memory or understanding correlate with length and quality of retention?

---

I'm still new to this site. I try to phrase the same question in different ways.

Comment: What's the best way to facilitate learning? That's the big question! I don't believe there is one answer for this, having worked with different and diverse populations, what works somewhere does not work everywhere. For me, however, I have found success (high school) with motivation and meta-cognitive strategies.  Knowing when to continue drilling or explore comes down to proper assessment (and some intuition).  Also depends on your goal. If they're preparing for a standardized test, I hate to say drilling tends to be effective. But hopefully there is more to education than those tests!